# Coroutines limits?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have some questions about Coroutines: Can I launch a large numbers of Coroutines, with heavy work, in parallel?

For example, I have a list of objects, and for each object I want to do some heavy work.

- Can I do a `for` loop and launch a Coroutine for each object in one time?
- How Coroutine can handle a large number of works in parallel?
- If memory is too low, Coroutine will wait before launching another Coroutine?
- It is better to limit Coroutines with a newFixedThreadPoolContext for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I launch a large numbers of Coroutines, with heavy work, in
>   parallel?

Yes, you can. `Coroutines` are really lightweight. In fact a lot of coroutine examples show you can launch thousands of coroutines at a time.

> Can I do a For loop and launch a Coroutine for each object in one time
>   ?

Yes, you can. Although I do not know how efficient that would be.

> How Coroutine can handle a large number of work in parallel ?

Coroutines have the notion of `Dispatchers` which allow you to configure threading.

> If memory is too low, Coroutine will waits before launch another
>   Coroutine ?

Coroutines behave like lightweight `Threads`, so memory management is up to you. I am not aware of a built in mechanism that would prevent a coroutine from being launched if the system does not have enough memory. Again, coroutines are lightweight so if you cannot launch a coroutine, there is probably something wrong going on.

> It is better to limit Coroutines with a newFixedThreadPoolContext for
>   example ?

By using `newFixedThreadPoolContext`, you are not really limiting the number of coroutines you can launch. You are just enforcing a limit on the `ThreadPool` that will be created to launch the coroutine. Also from the `newFixedThreadPoolContext` [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-fixed-thread-pool-context.html) note that it will be replaced in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! 
Another question, if I've to do some heavy works, like image processing on a list of images for example. Is it better to launch coroutines one at time, or to launch all coroutines at same time ?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: As long as your per-element wokload is heavier than a millisecond or so, you can start a coroutine for each. With lighter work, you should employ batching because there's overhead to handing off work between threads.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. Yes it takes more than a millisecond by element.